# How to clear content on a collection view layout ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I am developing a iOS app in which i am using a customized collection view. in the menu bar it has list of 3 controller 1, 2, 3. when i select 2 i want to create a new collection view layout and clear the previous one . Is it possible to clear data from previous collection view layout. Collection view is being created programmatically iOS.

This is my piece of code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"indexpath :    %ld",(long)indexPath.row);

    if(((long)indexPath.row==0)  && (indexPath.section==0)){
        HelpController *three=[[HelpController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpController" bundle:nil];
        [ self presentViewController:three animated:YES completion:nil];
        // [self.navigationController pushViewController:three animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"Help");

    }
    if(((long)indexPath.row==1)  && (indexPath.section==0)){

            backupController *bckup=[[backupController alloc]initWithNibName:@"backupController" bundle:nil];
            [self presentViewController:bckup animated:YES completion:nil];
           // [self.navigationController pushViewController:bckup animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"BackUp");

    }
    if(((long)indexPath.row==2)  && (indexPath.section==0)){
        NSLog(@"Children");
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    if(((long)indexPath.row==3)  && (indexPath.section==0)){
        AboutusController *three=[[AboutusController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutusController" bundle:nil];
        [ self presentViewController:three animated:YES completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"AboutUS");

    }
    if(((long)indexPath.row==4)  && (indexPath.section==1)){
        AddChildViewController *three=[[AddChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddChildViewController" bundle:nil];
        [ self.navigationController pushViewController:three animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"AboutUS");

    }
    if(((long)indexPath.row==0)  && (indexPath.section==1)){


        NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                stringForKey:@"firstchild"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:savedValue forKey:@"childname"];

        [[childDBHelper sharedInstance] createDatabase];

        AddChildViewController *add =[[AddChildViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddChildViewController" bundle:nil];
        [add navigatenext];
        //  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:];
        [self viewWillAppear:YES];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
    if(((long)indexPath.row==1)  && (indexPath.section==1)){


        NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                stringForKey:@"secondchild"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:savedValue forKey:@"childname"];

        [[childDBHelper sharedInstance] createDatabase];

        AddChildViewController *add =[[AddChildViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddChildViewController" bundle:nil];
         [add navigatenext];
      //  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:];
        [self viewWillAppear:YES];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
    if(((long)indexPath.row==2)  && (indexPath.section==1)){


        NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                stringForKey:@"thirdchild"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:savedValue forKey:@"childname"];

        [[childDBHelper sharedInstance] createDatabase];

        AddChildViewController *add =[[AddChildViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddChildViewController" bundle:nil];
        [add navigatenext];
        //  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:];
        [self viewWillAppear:YES];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
    if(((long)indexPath.row==3)  && (indexPath.section==1)){


        NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                stringForKey:@"fourthchild"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:savedValue forKey:@"childname"];

        [[childDBHelper sharedInstance] createDatabase];

        AddChildViewController *add =[[AddChildViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddChildViewController" bundle:nil];
        [add navigatenext];
        //  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:];
        [self viewWillAppear:YES];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }


}
```

even after selecting index path 2 in section tableview section one my menu bar does not hide and the previous collection view data still exist in layout .

Comment: why not reload the same collection view with ur new data

Comment: can u tell me how shud i reload the collection view with new data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


    [self.yourcollectionView reloadData];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call:

```
[collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidate];
```

Comment: i tried your method. But still having the same issue.

Comment: YoursLayout *layout = [[YoursLayout alloc] init];

Comment: [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout];